# bookshelf.js count method

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I was searching high and low to find how to do basic counting (like SELECT COUNT(something) FROM table) with Bookshelf.js, but to no avail. Is there anything I'm missing? Or is it just used with a manual select query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For now it's a manual query... e.g:

```
bookshelf.knex(tableName).count('columnName').then(...
```

Long story as to why that's the case, but it's mainly because of a few complexities around counts in relations, I don't want to hack a half working one on there just for the sake of having it there for the time being... the ultimate solution is going to be to have:

```
model.query().count(column).then(...
```

But currently that mutates the knex query builder instance, so doesn't quite work. I've been working on a big refactor of knex and I'm looking to get this implemented in the near future.

Comment: Just checking if you've made any progress on this?

Comment: Yes, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48368312/504930) below.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the format that I'm currently using to do the following from a model:

```
var Sample = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'example',

  count: function (cb) {
    bookshelf.knex('example')
      .count('id')
      .then(function (count) {
        cb(null, count)
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        cb(err)
      })
  }
})
```

Now, to count this table, simply call

```
new Sample().count(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since version 0.8.2 you can just use the `Collection#count()` method:

```
User.collection().count().then(function(count) {
  // count === 15
})
```

This can be used on any collection, like a model's relation:

```
User.forge({id: 1}).related('comments').count().then(function(count) {
  // count === 16
})
```

It can also be used on Model classes as a static method:

```
User.count().then(function(count) {
  // count === 15
})
```

It also accepts a column name to filter the results of the count by excluding rows whose value is `NULL` and will take into consideration any other defined query constraints:

```
User.count('is_active').then(function(count) {
  // count === 8
})

User.where('status', 'single').count().then(function(count) {
  // count === 4
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really simple solution just use **Bookshelf.knex.raw('count(id) as count')**

```
ReactionsDb
    .query(function(qb) {
      qb.groupBy('reaction_type');
    })
    .fetchAll({columns: ['reaction_type', Bookshelf.knex.raw('count(id) as count')]});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//user.js
var db = require('./db');
var User = db.Model.extend({  
  tableName: 'users',
  hasTimestamps: true,
});
module.exports = User; 

//main.js
var User = require('./user');
User.where('pet', 'dog').count('*').then(function(count) {
  console.log("Total Count : " , count);
});
```

In the above code snippet `User` is a model having the attributes like `pet` and `name`.

The generated query will be as follows: `select count(*) from user where pet='dog';`

Answer (score 0):

```
User.collection().query(function (qb) {
  qb.join('courses', 'users.id', 'courses.user_id');
  qb.groupBy('users.id');
  qb.select("users.*");
  qb.count('* as course_count');
  qb.orderBy("course_count", "desc");
})
```